# Assembly : Input value from user (more then one input)

Tags: assembly, input, bios, emu8086

This is a function in assembly to take input from the user in 2 strings "size" and "per",
but it only takes 1 input and then starts crashing.

I need help. Thank you in advance.

```
input:
mov si,0
lb :
mov ah,0
int 16h
cmp al,0x0d
je 2nd
mov [size + si],al
inc si
loop lb
2nd:
mov si,0
lb1:
mov ah,0
int 16h
mov [per + si],al
cmp al,0x0d
je 3rd
inc si
loop lb1
3rd:
ret
```

Comment: This can't crash in 16b real mode on itself. Also it doesn't show how you set `cx` before first iteration. And if you exhaust `cx` with first input, using full length, the second input will use `cx=0` as starting point, making 65536 characters long input possible, which will surely overwrite some memory in x86-16. Plus you have code duplicity, both parts are same, just put them into single routine, and debug that one, then call it with arguments like `mov si,OFFSET size` or `MOV si,OFFSET per`... Anyway, [MCVE] or I will vote for closing this, as you didn't show enough code which is relevant.

Comment: And emu8086 has built-in debugger, you may want to use it to verify all your assumptions about values in registers/memory/etc, that will also allow you to far better describe at which instruction the result is different from your expectations. "crashing" description is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a loop it's not mandatory to use the `loop` instruction!

In your 1st loop, after storing the character in *size* and after incrementing the pointer in `SI`, you need to always jump back to the top of your loop. The correct instruction then is `jmp lb`, an unconditional jump to the label *lb*.

```
input:
    mov si, 0
lb :
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    cmp al, 0x0d
    je  2nd
    mov [size + si], al
    inc si
    jmp lb              ; The unconditional jump
2nd:
```

In your 2nd loop, after incrementing the pointer in `SI`, you need to always jump back to the top of this loop. The correct instruction then is `jmp lb1`, an unconditional jump to the label *lb1*.

```
    mov si, 0
lb1:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    mov [per + si], al
    cmp al, 0x0d
    je  3rd
    inc si
    jmp lb1             ; The unconditional jump
3rd:
    ret
```

One thing that you should be aware of is where you check for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key (ASCII 13):

- The 1st loop checks it **before** storing in memory and thus no carriage return is attached to the string *size*.
- The 2nd loop checks it **after** storing in memory and thus a carriage return is attached to the string *per*.

This difference is probably not what you expect.